# Why do Babel helpers for decorators get inline'd in every module even when using transform-runtime?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

My config:

```
{
    test: /\.(js)$/,
    loaders: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: [
            [`env`, {
                loose: true,
                modules: false
            }],
            `stage-0`
        ],
        plugins: [
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            [
                'transform-runtime',
                {
                    polyfill: false,
                    regenerator: true
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
},
```

Most of Babel helpers are imported from `babel-runtime` module, however, not true for `_initDefineProp` and `_applyDecoratedDescriptor` and `_initializerWarningHelper`.

What did I do wrong? Why are those helpers not imported ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only the helpers that are developed by Babel's core system are exposed in `babel-runtime`. Since `decorators-legacy` is maintained as a separate repo in Babel 6, there is no way for the helpers to be shared in `babel-runtime`.

It is possible that in Babel 7 `legacy` could be maintained as part of Babel's core system, which would allow this.

For now, there is no way around this. That said, once files are gzipped, I wouldn't expect the repeated helpers to make a ton of difference size-wise.

Comment: I was trying to confuse webpack with `ProvidePlugin`, pointing all those helpers to my predefined module, but guess that's not how it works. I'll just go with that then. I'll have around 100 modules, each probably with decorators, a bit of a big deal.